# Doesn't navigate to authenticated page after login

Tags: redux, react-redux, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and Redux. I am trying to implement authentication using JWT and Redux

In my Redux devtool, I'm seeing isAuthenticated set to true. However, I m still able to access my login page and it doesn't automatically navigate me to the profile page. In fact, the below code doesn't seem to run at all! Anyone encounter this and has a solution? Thanks

```
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    navigate(`/app/profile`)
  }
```

Full code for Login Page

```
const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ email: "", password: "" })

  const { email, password } = formData

  const onChange = e => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    login(email, password)
  }

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    navigate(`/app/profile`)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Log in</h1>
      <FormContainer onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <InputContainer>
          <Input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={email}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <InputContainer>
          <Input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={password}
          />
        </InputContainer>
        <ButtonContainer>
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
        </ButtonContainer>
        <Link to="/app/register">
          <Linker content="Not a Member Yet?" />
        </Link>
      </FormContainer>
    </>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login)
```

Comment: Do you mutate the state in the reducer? Are the right actions dispatched and do they change the state correctly (you can check redux dev tools or do a console.log).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspect its the stateless JWT which caused the issue. I'm investigating the issue. Thanks for the tip :)